# How to replicate tables from multiple RDS databases into a single database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Here's the use case:

- We are going to have multiple Postgres DBs, each serving a different service. For instance, reviewDB serving review-service and mediaDB serving media-service. These DBs will be hosted in AWS RDS. They may share the same RDS instance, or some of them on dedicated RDS instances depending on the load.
- Meanwhile, I want to be able to sync all the tables from all those DBs into a separate database for analytics/report purposes(e.g. so that we can join tables from different DBs). Replication lag would be ok if it is less than 30 minutes.

Would this type of multi-db-to-single-db replication easy to set up on AWS? Like how easily AWS RDS allow us to set up H/A pair and read-replicas.

Comment: @JNevill I know what the major factors are, but my goal in this post was to specifically figure out whether this type of sync can *easily* be configured through AWS/RDS functionalities. Easy means, like the way RDS allows us to set up H/A pair and read-replicas.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought you were still in the "How the hell would I do this" phase. Not in the "I intend to use specifically this tool, what problems might pop up given my architecture" phase. I will remove my initial comment.